# Configuring Build of GDC with GCC 4.8 Snapshot

Tags: gcc, compilation, d, snapshot

I'm trying to build GDC from source. I've followed [these instructions](http://dgcc.sourceforge.net/gdc/install.html) and copied the `gdc`, `testsuite` and `libphobos` sub-directories into the GCC root directory. But I don't understand how to call the script `setup-gcc.sh`. The instructions says to call it without arguments as

```
./gcc/d/setup-gcc.sh
```

but then it just returns and says

```
Usage: ./setup-gcc.sh [OPTION] PATH
```

So

- **where** should I put this script,
- **from where** should I call it and
- what should its **argument** `PATH` be set to?

My directory structure so far is

```
- gcc (existing GCC git clone root)
  - libphobos (ADDED)
  - gcc (existing)
    - d (ADDED)
    - testsuite (existing)
      - gdc.test (ADDED)
      - lib (existing)
        - gdc*.exp (ADDED)
```

Comment: Those instructions are very old. The current instructions are here: http://gdcproject.org/wiki/Installation/ BTW: I think gdc doesn't work with very recent GCC-4.8 snapshots right now. 20121202 should work IIRC

Comment: Sorry, ibuclaw just pushed an update yesterday, the most recent gcc snapshot should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't put the script anywhere.
You call it from the same folder it is located.
The argument PATH should be the location of the GCC sources.

example:

```
./setup-gcc.sh ../gcc-4.8-snapshot
```

You also make a separate build directory.

```
mkdir objdir
```

And call ./configure from there

```
cd objdir
../gcc-4.8-snapshot/configure --enable-languages=d --enable-checking=release
```

Comment: My fault. I had forgotten that I hade made a change to the script. That's why it failed. Sorry and thanks. Now I'll go and see if GDC builds!

Comment: Build successful! Thanks again.